# How to visit path with anchor in Cucumber step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I need to check the link, that is not on the page. I should follow some path with existed anchor (#check, for example). How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have not given much details about your problem, but from this scarce information you've supplied I conclude that you're doing something naughty.

This is because while writing acceptance or integration tests with `Cucumber` you should have no need for 'checking a link that's not on a page'.

Anyways, you haven't mentioned what framework you're using with `Cucumber`. Assuming you're using `Capybara`, you can define a step like this:

```
And /^Invis is doing something naughty right now $/ do
  @some_thing = SomeThing.first 
  visit hidden_link_with_anchor_path(@some_thing, :anchor => "foo" )
end
```

Hope that helps.